# Função replace não funciona para todos os casos

Tags: python-3.x

Fiz esse script para ler um arquivo TXT, encontrar uma sequencia de 20 digitos no texto, e renomear o arquivo com a sequencia de digitos encontrada.
Usei o `replace` pra retirar todos os caracteres que aparecem entre os números, mas de alguma forma ele não removeu os hífens ao renomear.

```
name_files5 = os.listdir(path_txt)

for TXT in name_files5:
    with open(path_txt + '\\' + TXT, "r") as content:
        search = re.search(r'(?:\d(?:[\s,.\-\xAD_]|(?:\\r)|(?:\\n))*){20}', content.read())
    if search is not None:
        name5 = search.group(0)
        name5 = name5.replace("\n", "")
        name5 = name5.replace("\r", "")
        name5 = name5.replace("n", "")
        name5 = name5.replace("r", "")
        name5 = name5.replace("-", "")
        name5 = name5.replace("\\", "")
        name5 = name5.replace("/", "")
        name5 = name5.replace(".", "")
        name5 = name5.replace(" ", "")
        fp = os.path.join("20_digitos", name5 + "_%d.txt")
        postfix = 0
        while os.path.exists(fp % postfix):
            postfix += 1
        os.rename(
            os.path.join(path_txt, TXT),
            fp % postfix
        )
```

Fiz outros laços para encontrar outras sequencias para outras sequencias de mais ou menos dígitos, usando o replace do mesmo modo, inclusive para o hífen e funcionou sem problemas

edição: exemplo de como a sequencia aparece no texto, e como ele renomeou o arquivo, o "_0" é apenas um incremento pra diferenciar os arquivos quando já tiver um com o mesmo nome

Como aparece no texto:

> 0001018-­88.2011.5.02.0002

Como renomeou:

> 0001018­-8820115020002_0

Comment: Coloque também um exemplo de texto para o qual esse código falha.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida feito

Comment: @matt
Se você só quer os números, então pode fazer algo mais simples, como:

`''.join([letter for letter in name5 if letter.isdigit()])`

ou ainda

`filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), name5)`

Isso simplificaria bastante e talvez resolva o problema

Comment: Há vários caracteres no unicode que "parecem" hífen mas não são. A dica do @klaus acima para filtrar só os dígitos é melhor do que o que você está fazendo, de qualquer forma.

Answer (score -1):

Vai uma referência para você. Com certeza conseguirá implementar para salvar o arquivo.

```
import re
import os
from os import path

def search_files(prefix:'Uso: /home/user'):
    if not path.lexists(prefix):
        raise FileNotFoundError('Diretório ou arquivo não existe!')

    if path.isfile(prefix):
        return list(prefix)

    return [path.join(prefix, file) for file in os.listdir() if path.isfile(file)]

def map_numbers_in_files(prefix:'Uso: /home/user ou /home/user/file.txt'):
    absolute_path_files = search_files(prefix)

    if not absolute_path_files: 
        raise FileNotFoundError('Não existem arquivos nesse diretório.')

    pattern = re.compile(r"[\d]+")

    print('Numero'.ljust(25), 'Arquivo', sep='\t', end='\n\n')
    for path_file in absolute_path_files:
        with open(path_file) as file:
            for line in file.readlines():
                _matchs = pattern.findall(line)
                numbers = ''.join(_matchs)
                if numbers:
                    print(numbers.ljust(25), path_file, sep='\t')



map_numbers_in_files('/home/runner')

"""
Numero                      Arquivo

0                           /home/runner/_test_runner.py
1                           /home/runner/_test_runner.py
1                           /home/runner/_test_runner.py
1                           /home/runner/.bashrc
1                           /home/runner/.bashrc
1                           /home/runner/.bashrc
1000                        /home/runner/.bashrc
2000                        /home/runner/.bashrc
1                           /home/runner/.bashrc
1                           /home/runner/.bashrc
48                          /home/runner/.bashrc
6429                        /home/runner/.bashrc
1033013203300033013403300   /home/runner/.bashrc
1                           /home/runner/.bashrc
101                         /home/runner/.bashrc
01310135013601320101        /home/runner/.bashrc
1                           /home/runner/.profile
022                         /home/runner/.profile
1                           /home/runner/.bash_logout
1                           /home/runner/.bash_logout"""
```